# How do I delete the first column of a pandas dataframe, the name of the column is unknown

Tags: python, pandas

This is what I am currently using to delete the first column of a dataframe:

```
df1 = df1.iloc[:, 1:]
```

as it has not worked for some reason,

How to delete the first column of a pandas dataframe when the name of the column is unknown?

Comment: How has it not worked? What is the input data?

Answer (score 2):

you can delete any column with this but in your case, the first column is in `index = 0`, so:

```
df1.drop(df1.columns[0], axis=1)
```